# Ruling on having kids after marriage

Tags: nikah, children

Is it mandatory to have kids after marriage? What is the ruling on this in Islam?

I am asking this question in terms of couples who are perfectly healthy and can have babies but still choose not to have one their whole life.

Answer (score 0):

An Ustadh of the Maliki Madhab with whom I studied had answered this question by saying that it was permissible, provided that the 2 spouses agree and are not forced, as each has a right to descendants.

Comment: So it is permissible to not have kids after marriage right

Comment: Yes, with the conditions mentioned yes, although for some it would be Makruh at the Maliki. For the other schools, I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

‍In many places, Quran says children together wealth, like

> Wealth and children are [but] adornment of the worldly life. But the
> enduring good deeds are better to your Lord1 for reward and better for
> [one's] hope. [Quran 18:46](https://quran.com/18/46)

But just like there is no wrong in earning wealth in allowed (halal) ways, there is nothing wrong in trying to have good children. Actually in Quran, you can see it is always recommended to always pray for righteous children

> And those who say, "Our Lord, grant us from among our wives and
> offspring comfort to our eyes and make us a leader [i.e., example]
> for the righteous." [Quran 25:74](https://quran.com/25/74)

Also, it is not right to not have children fearing poverty. During pre Islamic period, infanticide was popular fearing poverty.

> Do not kill your children for fear of poverty. We provide for them and
> for you. Surely killing them is a heinous sin. [Quran 17:31](https://quran.com/17/31)

Having righteous children who will pray for you is one of the 3 things that do not stop even after your death.

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "When a man dies, his deeds come to
> an end, except for three: A continuous charity, knowledge by which
> people derive benefit, **pious son who prays for him.**"
> https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:949

So it is always recommended to try and pray to have righteous children and it cannot be said as mandatory. Because for some people Allah will not grant children even if they try.

> Or He bestows both males and females, and **He leaves barren whom He
> will**: for He is full of Knowledge and Power. [Quran 42:50](https://quran.com/42/50)

Comment: "...... pious son who prays for him." ==> Is this not applicable to daughter prayer and if a female dies?

Also, it is not right to not have children fearing poverty. During pre Islamic period, infanticide was popular fearing poverty. ==> I am not asking about killing infants after birth. I am asking that what if a person who is well settled and earns well do not wish to have children.

Comment: I understood what you are asking, just like killing infants fearing poverty, I was just saying we need not fear poverty when deciding to have children or not.  About "pious son who prays for him" walad can be used for son or child, so it should be translated "child" here. Also the hadeeth uses when an insan (human) dies, so it can be man or female.

Comment: Ok! So it is recommended to have children but not mandatory to have, right?

Answer (score -1):

In the name of Allah
It is not mandatory